# ADO with Provider that connects to SQL Server with Web Services/HTTP tunnel?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, oledb, ado

Our DB application is based on ADO with MS Ole DB Provider for SQL Server or uses the native SQL client driver.

In Delphi we use `TADOConnection` which is a simple a wrapper interface for ADO.

My hope is to use a provider suitable for `TADOConnection`/ADO (and `TADODataSets` etc...) that uses a transparent web-services/HTTP tunnel to send and receive data from SQL Server instead of using persistent connection to the SQL Server via SQL Server ports.

Does such a provider exists?

A very good analogy added by Sir Rufo in the comments (unfortunately It's for MySQL):

http://www.devart.com/mydac/docs/index.html?network_tunneling.htm

Comment: I know this for MySQL and MyDAC http://www.devart.com/mydac/docs/index.html?network_tunneling.htm

Comment: It's not that hard to write this yourself...

Comment: @whosrdaddy, "It's not that hard to write this yourself" I don't have a slight clue where to begin! :( Is it that easy to write my own provider?

Comment: This is the reason that webservices exist in the first place :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy, Yes but I need to switch an Existing framework. not write it again from scratch. I know how to consume web-services. how is that relevant to my question? when I was asking for a Provider driver for ADO...

Comment: Just giving some options, that's all. Exposing a SQL server over the web always poses some risks...

Comment: @HK1, this has nothing to do with ado.net

Comment: And sorry, I still don't understand how this is a duplicate, when I was very specific in my question and did not asked for workarounds that are not related to `ADO Provider`...